# In how many ways can I put objects from set N={At,Bi...Xy} into K boxes.

Tags: combinatorics

In how many ways can I put objects from set N={At,Bi...Xy} into K boxes. Where t, i,...y is number of particular object in N. For example N={A3,B2} is the same as N={A,A,A,B,B}. A box can also contain 0 objects.

Comment: Does order of objects in each box matters?

Comment: This is a [permutation of a multiset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation#Permutations_of_multisets).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the set $N = \{A_t,B_i,...,X_y\}$ contains 24 different elements and $|N| = t +i+...+y $.  We have $k$ boxes containing $0$ to $t+i+...+y$ objects. We can demonstrate the box-object system as **AA...A..|..|..BB..B...| ... | | .. XX ..** representing a string with $k-1$  walls of a box ( | ) and $t+i+...+y$ elements of $N$.

Total length of a string is $|N|+k-1$ and assuming that order does not matter, we divide the total amount of permutations $(|N|+k-1)!$ by duplicating sublines.

By multinomial coefficient, the total amount is

$\binom{|N|+k-1}{(k-1),t,i,...,y} = \frac{(|N|+k-1)!}{(k-1)!t!i!...y!}$